# Calculate angle, while knowing the cosine in R

Tags: r, trigonometry, angle

I need to calculate the angle of a triangle in R. I have the cosine value of the angle.

Is there any function through which I can find the angle by placing the cos value?

Comment: You need `acos`

Comment: Or if you want degrees `180 * acos(x) / pi`

Comment: And remember that there will be multiple angles giving the same cosine value:  you might not get the one you want.  The `atan2()` function takes both sine and cosine as arguments, and that makes the answer unique (up to multiples of full rotations).